# Смена картинки в зависимости от value select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ситуация такая: есть 2 селектa, в первом тип машины, во втором модель машины. Значения во втором селекте меняются в зависимости от выбора в первом селекте. При выборе во втором селекте должна меняеться картинка модели машины,но я не могу понять, как это сделать.

Вот код:

```js
var mkLists = new Array(4) 
mkLists["empty"] = ["Выберите марку машины"]; 
mkLists["passenger"] = ["Hyundai", "Toyota Camry 40", "KIA Optima"]; 
mkLists["BusinessClass"] = ["Toyota Land Cruiser", "Mercedes-Benz S 350-l", "Mercedes-Benz S 500-l", "KIA Cadenza", "Ssangyong Chairman Limo"]; 
mkLists["Multiplace"] = ["Mercedes Benz Tourismo", "Hyundai Aero City", "Hyundai Universe Luxury", "Hyundai Counti", "Toyota Coaster", "Toyota hiace"]; 
mkLists["SpecMachinery"]= ["Газ 330232", "Газ 330202", "Камаз 45143", "Прицеп (Камаз 45143)"]; 

function mkChange(selectObj) { 
  var id = selectObj.selectedIndex; 
  var which = selectObj.options[id].value; 
    carsList = mkLists[which]; 
  var carSelect = document.getElementById("brand"); 
  while (carSelect.options.length > 0) { 
    carSelect.remove(0); 
  } 
  var newOption; 
  for (var i=0; i<carsList.length; i++) { 
      newOption = document.createElement("option"); 
      newOption.value = carsList[i];  
      newOption.text=carsList[i];
      try {
          carSelect.add(newOption);
      } 
      catch (e) {
          carSelect.appendChild(newOption);
      } 
  } //конец цикла 
} //конец функции
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select id="mk" onchange="mkChange(this);">
    <option value="empty">Выберите тип машины</option>
    <option value="passenger">Легковой</option>
    <option value="BusinessClass">Бизнес класс</option>
    <option value="Multiplace">Многоместный</option>
    <option value="SpecMachinery">Спецтехника</option>
  </select>

  <select id="brand">
    <option value="0">Выберите марку машины</option>
  </select>
</form>

<img src="">
```

Если какие-то неясности - спрашивайте. Заранее спасибо

Comment: покажите код плиз

Comment: Непонятно в чём состоит ваша проблема и как её воспроизвести без описания и кода.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kaqiruyaya/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Aiba пожалуй, стоило уточнить: код должен быть в самом вопросе. И в чём всё-таки проблема?

Comment: не получается сделать так чтобы при выборе во втором селекте с моделями менялись картинки в зависимости от выбранной модели

Comment: @Aiba в представленном коде (который, надеюсь, вы всё же добавите в сам вопрос) нет ни одной картинки. Какие же картинки тогда должны меняться?

Comment: картинки будут с изображением модели машин перечисленных в массиве

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать таким простым образом, с использованием объекта.
P.S. в следующий раз, поменьше комбинаций пишите, я 10 минут искал картинки :)

```js
var mkLists = new Array(4) 
mkLists["empty"] = ["Выберите марку машины"]; 
mkLists["passenger"] = ["Hyundai", "Toyota Camry 40", "KIA Optima"]; 
mkLists["BusinessClass"] = ["Toyota Land Cruiser", "Mercedes-Benz S 350-l", "Mercedes-Benz S 500-l", "KIA Cadenza", "Ssangyong Chairman Limo"]; 
mkLists["Multiplace"] = ["Mercedes Benz Tourismo", "Hyundai Aero City", "Hyundai Universe Luxury", "Hyundai Counti", "Toyota Coaster", "Toyota hiace"]; 
mkLists["SpecMachinery"]= ["Газ 330232", "Газ 330202", "Камаз 45143", "Прицеп (Камаз 45143)"]; 

function mkChange(selectObj) { 
  var id = selectObj.selectedIndex; 
  var which = selectObj.options[id].value; 
    carsList = mkLists[which]; 
  var carSelect = document.getElementById("brand"); 
  while (carSelect.options.length > 0) { 
    carSelect.remove(0); 
  } 
  var newOption; 
  for (var i=0; i<carsList.length; i++) { 
      newOption = document.createElement("option"); 
      newOption.value = carsList[i];  
      newOption.text=carsList[i];
      try {
          carSelect.add(newOption);
      } 
      catch (e) {
          carSelect.appendChild(newOption);
      } 
  }
  checkimage($('#brand').val());
}

$('#brand').on('input', function() {
  checkimage(this.value);
});

function checkimage(val) {
  var arr = {
    'Hyundai': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsJn.jpg?s=48&g=1', 
    'Toyota Camry 40': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgiaU.gif?s=32&g=1', 
    'KIA Optima': 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b2f4cbdf639291342efd2d1b65aab9a5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1', 
    'Toyota Land Cruiser': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyqB8.jpg?s=32&g=1',
    'Mercedes-Benz S 350-l': 'http://carspravka.ru/images/auto/308364200902ee7538b0f1e820e90dd7.jpg',
    'Mercedes-Benz S 500-l': 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhkicI4gAw25_36ICerF5foHKolNKWo72syMnku1-heg7g8B7U',
    'KIA Cadenza': 'http://media.caranddriver.com/images/16q1/665058/2017-kia-cadenza-photos-and-info-news-car-and-driver-photo-667111-s-450x274.jpg',
    'Ssangyong Chairman Limo': 'https://madwhips.s3.amazonaws.com/photo_219_ssangyong_chairman_limo_1_33623_original.jpg',
    'Mercedes Benz Tourismo': 'https://cdn.riastatic.com/photos/auto/newauto_photos/62/6200/620059/620059f.jpg',
    'Hyundai Aero City': 'http://kortim.ru/images/stati/huindai-super-aero-sity/Hyundai_Super_Aero_City540_Euro4.jpg',
    'Hyundai Universe Luxury': 'http://fotobus.msk.ru/photo/07/87/06/787067.jpg',
    'Hyundai Counti': 'http://a2goos.com/data_images/galleryes/hyundai-county/hyundai-county-05.jpg',
    'Toyota Coaster': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Toyota_Coaster_Deluxe_of_China_TV_BA-227_20100531.jpg',
    'Toyota hiace': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Toyota_Hiace_H200_511.JPG',
    'Газ 330232': 'http://gruzovo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/330232_1-350x263.jpg',
    'Газ 330202': 'http://www.gaz-tranzit.ru/files/auto/img_2_745.jpg',
    'Камаз 45143': 'http://westwind-covenant.com/images/59.jpg',
    'Прицеп (Камаз 45143)': 'http://autoline.com.ua/img/s/gruzovik-gruzovik-zernovozKAMAZ-45143-012-62---4_big--12051014101772788100.jpg'
  };
  if(arr[val] != undefined){
    $('img').attr('src', arr[val]);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <select id="mk" onchange="mkChange(this);">
           <option value="empty">Выберите тип машины</option>
           <option value="passenger">Легковой</option>
           <option value="BusinessClass">Бизнес класс</option>
           <option value="Multiplace">Многоместный</option>
           <option value="SpecMachinery">Спецтехника</option>
    </select>

    <select id="brand">
           <option value="0">Выберите марку машины</option>
    </select>
</form>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsJn.jpg?s=48&g=1" width="250">
```

Comment: А что насчет хранения в качестве `value` (или `data-value`) непосредственно ссылки на картинку? Это упростит код.

Comment: Первоначальное значение `src`, по-хорошему, стоит привязать к первоначальному выбранному `<option>` с помощью кода.

Comment: Yuri спасибо то что надо!!!

Comment: @Aiba, не за что :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
 $(".model").change(function(){ //При изменении модели
  var img_id = $(".model").children("option:selected").attr("data"); // Получаем значение атрибута блока с изображением модели автомобиля который нужно показать на изображении
      $(".modelImg").fadeOut(1); // прячем все блоки с изображением автомобилей
      $(img_id).fadeIn(10); // показываем нужный блок с изображением автомобиля
 });
});
```

```css
.modelImg {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="model">
  <option>-</option>
  <option data="#model-1">Модель 1</option><!-- в data указываем id блока с изображением нужного автомобиля  -->
  <option data="#model-2">Модель 2</option><!-- в data указываем id блока с изображением нужного автомобиля  -->
  </select>

<div class="modelImg" id="model-1"> <!-- id идентефикатор нужного изображения выбраного в селекте  -->
  <img  src="" alt="Модель 1" /></div>
<div class="modelImg"  id="model-2">
  <img src="" alt="Модель 2" />
</div>
```

Comment: `fadeOut(1)`, в принципе, отработает (визуально) как `hide()`. Зачем тогда его использовать? Аналогично с `fadeIn(10)`.